# How does IPv6 and Windows Remote Desktop work?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote, windows-server-2012

Say I have a Windows Server KVM with only an IPv6 IP. Do I have to configure anything specifically for the IPv6 address? And when I want to connect to the server via remote desktop connect, would I then just put the IPV6 address in the remote desktop connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In order to connect to something that is on IPv6 only, you need every network device in the routing path to support IPv6.  If anything doesn't support IPv6, then you can sometimes use an IPv6 broker, who let you tunnel IPv6 over IPv4 until you get to them, then they route IPv6 to the destination.

If all of this is in place, then yes you can just put the IPv6 address in the RDP connect box, or its DNS address (if it has an AAAA record) just as you would an IPv4 device.